# order by string

Tags: sql

Need to order id on based date & sequence number descending

ID is the combination of some concatenate string value
BM- 6to8 digitCode- Date(DDMMYY)-SequenceNumber (01-99)

```
Create table #tempcheck (id varchar(50))
Insert into #tempcheck values('BM72220901021904')
Insert into #tempcheck values('BM72220901021906')
Insert into #tempcheck values('BM72220931011901')
Insert into #tempcheck values('BM72220931011903')
Select * from  #tempcheck order by id desc

id  
BM72220901021906  
BM72220901021904  
BM72220931011903  
BM72220931011901
```

Comment: which rdbms are you using?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and you are using non-standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: Maybe add a few columns for that date (as a date-datatype) and that sequence number (as integer)? Then your ORDER BY doesn't have to extract the parts

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
SELECT 
  *
from #tmpcheck
order by
  CONVERT(DATE, SUBSTRING(id, 9, 6)) AS date desc,
  CONVERT(int, RIGHT(id,2))  seq desc
```

**It is stated in the question that the part before the date can be of variable length**

```
SELECT 
  *
from #tmpcheck
order by
  CONVERT(DATE, SUBSTRING(RIGHT(id, 8), 1, 6)) AS date desc,
  CONVERT(int, RIGHT(id,2))  seq desc
```

Comment: It is stated in the question that the part before the date can be of variable length so this will not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, SUBSTRING(id, LEN(id) - 5, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(id, LEN(id) - 7, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(id, LEN(id) - 3, 2), 1) AS datevalue, RIGHT(id, 2) AS seq 
FROM #tempcheck 
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, SUBSTRING(id, LEN(id) - 5, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(id, LEN(id) - 7, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(id, LEN(id) - 3, 2), 1) DESC, RIGHT(id, 2) DESC
```

> [**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ae73c536783d6cdc0a4bf3cdab5427a5)

Answer (score 0):

This solution should do it. It uses only string manipulation (no data type conversion) and should be rather fast.

```
SELECT *
FROM #tempcheck 
ORDER BY Left(Right(id, 4), 2) + Left(Right(id, 6), 2)
       + Left(Right(id, 8), 2) + Right(id, 2) DESC
```

It does the character counting from the back end of the string so that the variable length (6-8) code before the date does not matter.